# Login form is not working with my code

Tags: php, database

The database is working, but when I try to login with the info I signed up with it just tells me information is incorrect as I told it to say that but I know info is right. I do not see a problem below so any help is 100% appreciated.  If you need to see more code I can post.

```
if (isset($_POST["user_login"]) && isset($_POST["password_login"])) {
    $user_login = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i', ' ', $_POST["user_login"]); // filter everything but numbers and letters
    $password_login = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i', ' ', $_POST["password_login"]); // filter everything but numbers and letters
    $password_login_crypt = crypt($password_login);
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE username='$user_login' AND password='$password_login_crypt' LIMIT 1"); // query
       //Check for their existence
       $userCount = mysql_num_rows($sql); //Count the number of rows returned
       if ($userCount == 1) {
           while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
                    $id = $row["id"];
       }
           $_SESSION["user_login"] = $user_login;
           header("location: home.php");
           exit();
           } else {
           echo 'That information is incorrect, try again';
           exit();
       }
}

?>
                <div style="width: 800px; margin: 0px auto 0px auto;">
                <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td width="60%" valign="top">
                                  <h2>Already a member? Sign in below!</h2>
                                  <form action="index.php" method="POST">
                                         <input type="text" name="user_login" size="25" placeholder="Username" /><br /><br />
                                         <input type="text" name="password_login" size="25" placeholder="Password" /><br /><br />
                                         <input type="submit" name="login" size="25" value="Login!" />
                                  </form>
```

My connection code. Marked ----- where my personal information really is.

```
<?php
mysql_connect("-----","-----", "-----") or die("Couldn't connect to SQL server");
mysql_select_db("-----") or die("Couldn't select DB");
?>
```

Comment: what happens when you `echo $userCount`? also, can you also include the connection code as well. You can mask your login info.

Comment: why are you filtering characters out of the password?

Comment: In all likelihood your query is returning 0 records. Check that the username and password combo exist.

Comment: Especially do a `echo $password_login_crypt;` and make sure it is identical to the one in the database

Comment: @Eli I posted my connection code. My sign up form takes the info into database so its working, just login is not.

Answer (score 1):

Crypt does not work the way you are using it.  It will return a different hash each time.  You may want to use the md5 function for a drop-in replacement, or look at the [PHP crypt documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php) for usage examples of crypt.

This is the code I usually use for crypt (Requires PHP >= 5.3.0):

```
//Generate
$password = 'password';
$salt = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(22));
$hash = crypt($password, '$2y$10$' . $salt);

//Validate
$valid = crypt($password, $hash) === $hash;
```

Since you already generated the hash, you should be able to use the validate part to check that your login/password is correct.  Just use the username to get the hash out of the database and do `$valid = crypt($password, $hash) === $hash;`

Comment: I had md5 in there before but I was told md5 was horrible. You know anything better than md5? I used crypt in my sign up form code, should that be ok? I mean it works so just wondering.

Comment: You are right that crypt would be more secure than md5.  I updated my answer with an example.